# How to turn on an LED on a certain distance with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, ping, led

I'm making an Arduino program and I can't get it to work.

All the program does is turn an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) on whenever someones becomes 5 inches away from the sensor. The problem is whenever I start the program the LED stays off no matter what. Here's my program

```
const int pingPin =7 ;
const int ledPin = 13;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    long duration, inches, cm;

    pinMode(pingPin,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pingPin,LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(pingPin,HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    digitalWrite(pingPin,LOW);

    pinMode(pingPin,INPUT);
    duration =pulseIn(pingPin,HIGH);

    inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

    Serial.print(inches);
    Serial.print("in, ");
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();
    delay(100);

    while (true) {
        if (inches <= 5) {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        }
    }
}

long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{
    return microseconds /74/2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
    return microseconds /29/2;
}
```

How can I fix this so that the LED turns on and off at the correct distances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at this last bit of your code:

```
while (true) {
  if (inches <= 5) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

You see what it is doing? It is looping forever.

So... your var `inches` gets a value once and then for all and eternity (or until you unplug) that value will remain the same..

Get rid of the `while()` and you should see some responsiveness (assuming everything else is hooked up correctly).

Comment: Thank you SO much! I can't believe I didn't see that

Comment: The only problem now is that it flickers randomly and when its turned on the LED comes on with it and start randomly flickering.

Comment: Well the flickering is a separate issue. I don't know what kind of sensor you are using - so there may be a core problem there (how it is set up, how much fluctuation there is in its readings, etc.). What's up with the delayMicroseconds + the delay(100)? I've found with noisy sensors (or environment) that it helps to take some number of readings (each `loop()`) and average them to determine a final value. Also, the print statements take some time to process so for a true test, comment them out (unless they are needed for your project).

Comment: Never mind I got it to work! All I did was cache the distance (in inches) into a variable and did if (inches < distance)

Comment: BTW: it is much shorter to write

`digitalWrite(ledPin, inches <= 5);`

Comment: @UdoKlein - more confusing for a beginner to do a comparison within a function call but yes, I agree it is shorter. Going further, s/he would be better off not to hard code the threshold limit (5) but instead define it in a var but ya gotta walk before you can run ;-)